# System Users for Chat

Tags: discussion, status-completed, users, chat

What are the System Users for Chat and what are the point of those users? They always seem to have negative user IDs.

I've been able to find 9 current System Users for Chat:

- [Feeds](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-2)
- [Gaming](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-3)
- [Meta Gaming](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-4)
- [Game Dev](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-5)
- [asp.net](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-6)
- [Feeds 24](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-7)
- [Server Fault](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-8)
- [C#](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-9)

Do these users differ at all from the Feeds user that runs feeds you add to a room, or are they specialized users? How are new users created? Eg. One for your favourite SE site so it can be invited into the room.

Comment: There's also Lazers on the Arqade chat ([user ID -23](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-23/lazers)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote:

> **This is a system user, used (for example) to represent an external data feed.**

They are *functionally* identical to the "Feeds" user.

Why is this useful? During our internal testing, we found it desirable to hide *one* feed, but not all of them. Besides, now we can get individual names and logos for each.

My plan is to detect SOFU/SE feeds and do some icon lookup via stackauth - but for now this is limited to ♦ mods: if you have a room with a feed (or feeds), they can click a button to give that feed an identity.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I figured.

Comment: hmm... what exactly has been "completed" here?

Comment: What's the "Chicken" user?