# What are the negative users on chat?

Tags: support, chat, users

I mean like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-42/clippy):

> [image: screenshot of chat user Clippy]

They aren't linked to any account.

Comment: Clippy exists here?!  *I don't want to live on this planet anymore...*

Comment: Clippy is Life, Universe and Everything. You cannot escape from it.

Comment: Ben has the truth of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are automated feeds: [System Users for Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59796/system-users-for-chat?rq=1) They're given a negative user number so they can't conflict with "real" users.